# difference between x servers in windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server, xming

I'm using Windows 10 Insider Preview with Windows subsystem for Linux enabled

I'm wondering what's the true differences between VcXsrv and Xming to view windows from Ubuntu in windows

I know the immediate differences with the settings, I meaning more specifics, like what's less resource intensive and maybe things to don't work on one but do with the other

The `Windows-10` tag does apply as this has existed since the AU in normal builds

Comment: Which version of Xming?  The really out of Date FOSS version, or the maintained non-free version?  The old foss version of xming acts buggy and unstable for me.

Comment: @Zoredache, The one available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) is the one that I mean

Comment: Right, the Foss version, whose newest build is almost 10 years old, compared to the non-free version that is http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/ which was last built yesterday.  Or the VcXsrv which was last updated about six months ago.  Anyway the point is that one major difference is that free xming is ancient, and in my experience buggy.

Comment: @Zoredache, ya, the FOSS version, I forgot what FOSS meant for a bit, i've been away from Ubuntu for too long

Comment: @Zoredache, how about the new Xming and VcXsrv? what's your comparison? is it worth to pay?

Comment: I haven't used it.  I have been meaning it to try VcXsrv at some point, just be busy with things.  I am using the paid Xming because I needed something  that worked, and I don't believe VcXsrv existed at the time, or I didn't know about it.  In your shoes for a new install, I would probably try using the VcXsrv before paying for Xming.

Comment: @Zoredache, VcXsrv isn't as well known because It didn't get much popularity and thus mainly unknown, but could you test it out?

Comment: for those of you who tried Xming, what kinds of bugs did you get? I just started using Xming on Win10, because I had somehow heard about Xming. Not sure whether I am headed for big headaches..

Comment: You might try installing the base + X package of cygwin.  It has an X server that is maintained and works well displaying X-apps from linux machines.  I've been using it for a little over 15 years.  The cygwin-X maintainer tries to keep it reasonably current with current releases and the cygwin is free.  As far as I know, the Xming version was derived from the cygwin version in the distant past.  I tried Xming, but had too many incompatibilities w/my environment and the dev refused to help when he found out I used cygwin...

Comment: For me, I'm using Xmng of 2007, it worked out of the box (installation) on Windows 10. But I find the display not very clear, like my short-sighted eyes without classes. It usually worked with my emacs running in Ubuntu in Windows for a couple of hours, then the display may freeze, or the size may shrink when dragging to different monitors. I want to to try VcXsrv, but the installation requires local admin privilege, which is not convenient to get for me.

Comment: There is also X410, which is polished but paid software

Comment: This comment is not a direct answer to the question but might help anyone looking for an answer to "What should I install on Windows 10/11 to display Linux GUI applications?": In recent WSL releases, Windows ships an X server: WSLg (https://github.com/microsoft/wslg).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) is a open source project under [GPLv3](https://sourceforge.net/p/vcxsrv/code/ci/master/tree/COPYING) license about building reliable X Server using Visual Studio in potentially optimal manner. It's common knowledge Microsoft Compilers are very good for Windows platform, since there are free variants it's tempting option. It was my first choice for X Server when I tried *Windows Subsystem for Linux* for the first time in Windows 10.

[Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) is a weird project which under term **Donation** hides a price for the installable binaries. I always though donations are voluntary, but it seems the author has different perception. This project was the only option to have X Server on Windows natively for very long time, but since we have VcXsrv, there is choice.

I personally have very good experience with VcXsrc, it's easy to install and works very fast. I'm surprised it's not more popular. As far as I know their code is more clean version of original X server and doesn't relate to Cygwin.

Comment: To put it in clearer terms: Xming's "donation", where you give its maker a fixed amount of 10 GBP and you get access to the download of the current major version of the software, seems exactly like a sale and very little like a donation.

Comment: I've used the "donation-ware" Xming for many years without any significant problems. Your "donation" should cover all future releases, but your credentials for downloading often "get's lost" and the support from the maintainer is flaky, so I have moved over to Vcxsrv and don't regret it.

Answer (score 13):

Both are compiled from modified X.org source code.

VcXsrv handles screen-shots correctly when you Alt-Tab between windows, and puts proper icons in the task-bar.  I haven't got that working with the Xming public domain version.

Xming comes with more programs to start-up, VcXsrv relies on Xlaunch.

On my Samsung Notebook 9 pen with Intel UHD 620 graphics, VcXsrv tries to do hardware acceleration by default, which doesn't work, don't know why.  I had to unclick the option when running Xlaunch.  Xming defaults straight to software OpenGL.

I had trouble with both version switching monitors on a Surface Book.  VcXsrv crashed, Xming just didn't display properly.