# X11 forwarding from a remote Linux server to a WSL2 desktop

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x11-forwarding

I need to run GUIs from a Linux server (which I do not have sudo for) for work.
Being on a Windows 11 computer, I set up a WSL with Ubuntu-22.04, and succesfully followed [these steps](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-wsl2-on-windows-11-with-gui-support#1-overview) to display Linux GUIs on my Windows system: `xeyes` and other related programs work as intended when working locally.

However, I haven't been able to run GUIs from my work server.

Here is an example with `xeyes`; the following error is printed:

```
myprofile@palaeoprime:~$ xeyes
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 44850
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 2
Error: Can't open display: palaeoprime:10.0
```

X11 forwarding is enabled on the server (`X11Forwarding yes`,`X11UseLocalhost no` and `X11DisplayOffset 10` are present in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), and Xauth is installed too.

When connecting to the server `ssh myprofile@serverIP -X -v`, I get the following text after putting in my password:

```
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "C.UTF-8"
```

Is there a solution for this, or is it more viable for me to install Xming locally and work from there?
This is my first post on Super User, my apologies if it is not detailed enough or poorly worded, more than happy to add edits if clarifications are needed.
Cheers!

Comment: Try running "ssh -Y" instead of "ssh -X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use WSL2.

Download [Xming X Server](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) by default it will set a X screen :0 for all your local ips.

Once you are connected to the server with ssh.  Set the DISPLAY Variable to your IP (Assuming you are using a VPN, use the VPN address) :0 and then export that variable to make it usable by other shells eg:

```
DISPLAY=10.212.111.200:0
export DISPLAY
```

Once connected from the cmd line run the X application, eg xfce4-terminal

Alternative solution would be to use VNC, you would need your admins to setup vnc.  Once setup, you can connect with VNC to the display allocated at login, and use the X11 App that way

Comment: I would do what this person suggest but I would use VcXsrv or the one built into MobaXTerm.  (free) MobaXTerm will even do the ssh part, set your DISPLAY variable for you, and provide a GUI FTP server without any additional configuration or installation.  15 seconds later, you will be logged in and launching GUI apps.  IMHO, Xming is not only [not very good](https://superuser.com/questions/1165151/difference-between-x-servers-in-windows).. but limits what you can do without a "donation".

Comment: MobaXTerm is a good solution, I used it when I was first learning remote X11.  Good suggestion

Comment: Note that if you follow this suggestion, you're not forwarding X through ssh, you're doing it directly over the network.

Comment: @Kenster - correct.  However if you are using a VPN that has been setup correctly, then the connection is encrypted.

Comment: This worked outfor me! cheers @LukeAttard